# Trying to solve "outside tablespace bounds" MySQL error, but recovering table with mysqldump fails

Tags: mysql, recovery

I am running MySQL on a Windows 2008 server. One of the tables (> 1 million records) seems to be corrupted. The mysql error log shows this:

```
InnoDB: Error: trying to access page number 197105 in space 89,
InnoDB: space name dbname/tablename,
InnoDB: which is outside the tablespace bounds.
InnoDB: Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type 10.
InnoDB: If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that
InnoDB: your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the
InnoDB: MySQL server.
```

Based on this error message, I checked my.cnf for the relevant lines:

```
innodb_data_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
```

This is exactly where the data resides. ibdata1 is about 208 MB in size, the tablename.ibd is about 4 GB in size. I've been using this server succesfully for many months.

After searching on this site and elsewhere, I tried to perform recovery as follows:

- Set innodb_force_recovery=1 and then up to 6.
- Next, dump the specific table with mysqldump. I am using this
  command: `mysqldump dbname tablename --user=root --password=blahblah.`
  During this dump, for recovery levels 1 through 3, mysql crashes ('goes away'). At 4, it managed to dump the first 23992 records, but then it said " Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table `tablename` at row: 23992". The log has some additional lines preceding what I showed above:

  `InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table "dbname"."tablename" 
  in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 89.
  InnoDB: Error: trying to access page number 0 in space 89,
  InnoDB: space name dbname/tablename,
  InnoDB: which is outside the tablespace bounds.`
- It seems as soon as I touch or (select) query this table, either through php, python or phpMyAdmin, mysql crashes.

Does anybody have any other suggestions, possibly based on the **tablespace bounds** error above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might be more successful by asking this on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Good suggestion, will do that. Thanks!